# Count for two column from a table using groupby or unionall based on users

Tags: php, mysql

I want count for two columns from a single query which are in same table.

1- **followerscount**

2- **followeecount**

I am using union and groupby to get count for two columns but only able to get only one column count from query.

Query I used below:

```
SELECT follow_attr.username, follow_attr.followerid, follow_attr.followeeid, follow_attr.followercount, follow_attr.followeecount 
 FROM (
    SELECT u.username, dff.followerid AS followerid, dff.followeeid AS followeeid, count(dff.followerid) AS followercount, count(dff.followeeid) AS followeecount
FROM tablename AS dff
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.userid = dff.followerid
GROUP BY dff.followerid
UNION ALL
SELECT u.username, dffs.followerid AS followerid, dffs.followeeid AS followeeid, count(dffs.followerid) AS followercount, count(dffs.followeeid) AS followeecount
FROM tablename AS dffs
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.userid = dffs.followeeid
GROUP BY dffs.followeeid
   ) AS follow_attr
WHERE follow_attr.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY follow_attr.followerid, follow_attr.followeeid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,6
```

I am not been able to get followeecount in this query.

Let me know whats wrong in that procedure.

Comment: `SUM()` or `COUNT()` should probably be in the outer query.

Comment: What we should used in place of that..and how could I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Do this 
**SELECT COUNT(followercount) AS f_count, COUNT(followeecount) AS fe_count FROM tablename**

Comment: Using this, It will automatically count it for you. So when you echo **$row['f_count']** it will give you the total number of followercount and when you echo **$row['fe_count']** it'll show the total number of followeecount

Comment: Actually f_count and fe_count is based on join with user table.